# Can I blend (with multiply) a UIImage to a simple UIView with GPUImage?

Tags: ios, uiview, uikit, gpuimage, blending

I just couldn't find it in the docs at the first sight.

It is clear that I can do almost every magic with two images, but can I composite stuff upon a simple UIKit hierarchy?

Comment: I did this when I was hanging around with OpenGL views upon UIKit (that was a screen blending) in this https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ompass360-augmented-reality/id384527808?mt=8 product. It is possible, maybe not implemented in GPUImage yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, straight from [Brad Larson](https://twitter.com/bradlarson/status/430758039818215424):

> You can pass the UIView into a GPUImageUIElement and blend from that source, but there might be a better way to do what you want.